# Adobe Acrobat import image javascript. Does it work on Acrobat Reader?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I created a button with importing image functionality using this script:

```
event.target.buttonImportIcon();
```

I know users with Acrobat Pro can import pictures however does anyone know if users with JUST Acrobat Reader can use this function? if so, is there any older versions that won't allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Reader can use buttonImportIcon() but the "image" must first be converted to PDF. The field method buttonImportIcon() never imports an image, it only imports a specific page of a PDF. It's just that with Acrobat, if the selected file is not a PDF ***and*** it can be converted to PDF, the conversion will happen automatically.

Comment: Thanks.
Is there a way to make it so users with Reader can import image files?

Comment: Nope. Reader can only import PDF. However, there are free hosted services that will wrap a PDF around your image file. Does the image have to be a button icon? If not, Reader users can copy the image onto the clipboard using the native OS image viewer and then simply paste it into the PDF. It will be added to the page as a stamp annotation.